# PHP length of String is higher than string?

Tags: php, xampp

i would like to import an csv file and I have got a problem to compare the result with a constant.
my file is looking something like this:
1;1;23
1;2,11
...
When I dumped the first row I got this result:

```
array (size=3)
    0 => string '﻿1' (length=4)
    1 => string '1' (length=1)
    2 => string '23' (length=2)
```

How the hell could be the result string '1' = length 4
I also returned the length of the string with strlen and also trim the string but i got everytime the result 4. Btw I use the PHP version 7.4 with xampp

Comment: There can be any invisible, zero-width characters. Try to check this string in hexadecimal editor.

Comment: Use `urlencode` on the value, then the percent encoding in the resulting output will quickly show you what actual byte values you are dealing with there …

Comment: check which encoding your file is using: file -bi filename.csv depending on encoding diffrent tools interprets those chars differently.